# Match all spaces and tabs in string except spaces and tabs inside quotes

Tags: regex

I have a text file full of lines in which the words are divided/separated by whether tabs, spaces or both. Here an example:

```
Line#xx: This  is   my       nickname "mad dog   1" and blah blah.
```

My question is, how can I match all tabs and spaces in that line, except the spaces and tabs inside those quotes?

Comment: You should look at lookaheads. http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html

Comment: Should your search also match `This  is   my       nickname "maddog1" and blah blah.` ? or should there be at least one space between them ?
`This  is   my       nickname "mad dog 1" and blah blah.` ?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to come out with the solution to this. Thanks Mike Cheel for the link.

The particular regex for this kind of problem is as follows:

> (\t|\s[?!(\")(.)(\")])

This works fine for my problem and I hope it helps someone else.